# Outlook folders gone after changing root folder path ("Stammordner pfad")

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap

I have an urgent problem with MS Outlook 2013 (German).

I have an IMAP e-mail account. When I was generating folders using Outlook in the inbox I mentioned that they are named "Foldername (only on this computer)".

After some googleling I found out that this might be related to the wrong setting of the Stammordnerpfad (ger) / root folder path (eng?).

So I set the root folder path to "Inbox".

The computer obviously synced again the IMAP folder.

However the original generated folders "Foldername (only on this computer)" were **gone** (including their mails)! Setting back the root folder path didn't help.

Any chance to get back my stored mails?

Comment: Imap account of gmx.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Outlook stores all "only on this computer" folders in OST cache file that can be easily deleted, refreshed or removed at any moment. This is exactly what happend when you re-synced your folders. Never use "only on this computer" folders, use server-side IMAP folders or at least create a new PST data file and use it to store mail locally more or less reliably.

Comment: I was afraid that I'll get such an anser. After testing > 5 tool for OST recovery none could find the missing folders.  Obviously I made some mistakes. (Changing settings w/o backup). But additionally I'm also a bit disapointed by Outlook, for the following reasons: (1) Why are new folders, within the INBOX not automatically generated on the IMAP server? If i had used an Exchange server, this would be the normal behaviour. I was assuming this to happe on my IMAP accout as well.

Comment: (2) No all local folders were marked with "only on this computer". So For some time i was assuming that these mails were stored in an IMAP folder, which was not the case. (3) Deleting data with is only availabel locally without issuing a warning message, is not very nice.     --- I take this as a lesson learnt. The damage happend is not too big, since this were mainly private mails. However....